# Passing arguments from C to 64bit linux Assembly

Tags: c, linux, assembly, 64-bit, att

I'm trying to write my first assembly function to be called from a C program. Here is the .c part:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int sum(int a, int b);

int main() {

printf("2+3 = %d\n", sum(2,3));

    return 0;
}
```

And the assembly part:

```
.text

.global sum

sum:

push %rbp
mov %rsp, %rbp

mov 8(%rbp), %rax
add 12(%rbp), %rax

pop %rbp

ret
```

According to some tutorials, arguments should be stored in %ebp (in 32bit version) register. However, when I compile the code above, I'm getting this result:

```
2+3 = 4195607
```

Could someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Oh, and here is the Makefile:

```
test: test.o testc.o
    gcc -o test test.o testc.o
test.o: f1.s
    gcc -o test.o -c f1.s
testc.o: f2.c
    gcc -c -o test.o f2.c
```

Thank you in advance for any tips!

Regards,
Filip

Comment: The 64 bit calling convention is different. You can get a quick overview at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). For full details consult the _System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement_ document.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply! Looking at the table, I can see that 64bit GNU/Linux compiler uses rdi, rsi, rdx and rcx registers for storing parameters. However, each of them returns a wrong value when tested like: mov 8(%rdi), %rax    or  mov 8(%rdx), %rax

Comment: @Jester All right, got it solved! It appears to be %rdi holding the first argument and %rsi the second one. Thank you very much!